# Yusuf AS in ancient egypt history

Tags: history, prophet-yusuf

Today, we have some information about ancient egyptian history, some of the pharahohs that existed. Is there any information regarding a figure who could be Yusuf AS in ancient egyptian history ?

Comment: https://josephandisraelinegypt.wordpress.com/2014/12/01/where-does-joseph-fit-into-egyptian-history/

Comment: probably better suited for [history.se]; see e.g. [this question](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/50449/is-biblical-joseph-story-historically-valid)

Comment: @G.Bach, I can try this, but the question would really need different content as people may not be aware of Yusuf AS (Joseph). Should probably add content like the occurrence of the famine...

Comment: @Noor The Quranic Yusuf is the same figure as the Biblical Joseph, and pretty much anyone with any historical interest in the ancient Middle East is going to be well aware of him - plus that community is much better equipped to answer historical questions than this one is.